# Множество элементами которого являются множества C++

Tags: c++

Надо придумать способ как хранить множество, элементами которого могут быть другие множества, в свою очередь у этих множеств элементами могут быть также множества и так далее.
УРОВЕНЬ ТАКИХ ВЛОЖЕНИЙ НЕ ОГРАНИЧЕН!!!!!. Не могу понять какой контейнер лучше использовать. Желательно не предлагать классы ,так как я не владею ими. Но мне мой метод не нравится он слишком сложный и я пока рисовал запутался, поэтому прошу подскажите как рациональнее все это сделать.

```
 struct element
{
int key;
element *next;
};


  struct mnoz
{
 element *el;
 mnoz *next;
 mnoz *podmn;
};
```

[image: Принцип дробить множество до тех пор пока не получим просты элементы,в ячейках я вписал значение элементов]

Comment: но таких вложений может быть миллиард, их все же не укажешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это дерево, в принципе-то.

```cpp
struct Node {
    int leaf;
    std::vector<Node> branches;
};
```

И, в принципе,можно придумать тысячи реализаций.

Comment: или linked list https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Связный_список

Comment: Да, спасибо так и сделаю, только наверное добавлю в структуру указатель на родителя это сделано для того чтобы было проще работать с ними  `struct Node {
    int leaf;
    std::vector<Node> branches;
    Node *parent;
};`